# Getting a "command not found: conda" message whenever I open terminal

Tags: terminal, python

I am running OS Ventura 13 on a Mac with an M1 chip. I've been trying (partially successfully??) to configure a python-based code repository on my computer but as I've been trying to download the program, I think I may accidentally complied multiple recursive versions of python (both complete and possibly partially deleted?) onto my computer. Now when I open terminal, I see this error message:

```
Last login: Thu Apr 27 16:24:01 on console  
/Users/username/.zshrc:17: command not found: conda
```

This is the what I get when I pull up my .zshrc file:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/user/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

conda activate mne
```

Can I delete this file without causing additional problems?

Comment: Open your `.zshrc` file and go to line 17.  What does it say?  You can comment it out for now - put a (`#`) at the beginning of the line.  Post an [edit] to the original question with these details

Comment: It appears you have an anaconda (backup) install that went sideways.  If that is all you have in your `.zshrc` file, then you can safely delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to delete. This is part of https://www.anaconda.com/ and removing it will not break your system (and based on the error message it isn't working anyway).

If you need anaconda dev environment again you may just follow setup instructions again.